# Can we use Bourbon in Grails?

Tags: grails, bourbon

I am new to Grails and Bourbon. Only compass-sass comes as a plugin in Grails.
Is it possible to use Bourbon in Grails? How do we install bourbon and use it in Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no Grails specific plugin for Bourbon. However, that does not exclude you from using it in your own build process for your project or writing your own extension that handles processing Bourbon files in conjunction with the [Grails Asset Pipeline plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline).

In fact the Grails Asset Pipeline plugin has entire section of the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/extending.html) that explains how to extend the plugin for handling new processors.